# You shouldn't need 50 rep to post a comment

Tags: discussion

I find it annoying that it requires 50 rep to comment on another post. I once asked a question and someone answered and provided a link. I tried the instructions at the link and completely screwed up Ubuntu. I couldn't comment and ask for help at the answer because I didn't have enough rep. While I understand that getting rid of the neccesity for rep to comment could lead to spam and other problems, I believe that people below 50 rep should be allowed to comment but it must be approved first, or you could lower the barrier to like 30-50. Alternatively you could just permit people to comment on links that are on answers to qiestions they have asked.

//I understand that this may have been placed in the wrong spot. I would be appreciative if someone moved this to correct location.

Thank You

Comment: You should be able to comment on answers of your own questions regardless of rep

Comment: Never ever follow instructions in links. If the one that wrote the answer didn't had the courtesy to write a complete answer they shouldn't have the same to get the rep.

Comment: Well the problem with that is that someone could potentially spam and if that account got banned they could just make another one and without any effort they could continue spanning things. However I think they should be able to after getting a few points so it is not so easy to spam.

Comment: @Braiam thank you, i'll remember that when I answer things to.

Comment: It only takes 50 rep to post comments, and you can always comment on your own posts and answers to your questions. It isn't as hard as you think to get 50 rep.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I understand that it may not be very hard to get 50 rep for someone who understands Ubuntu, but when someone joins Ubuntu they may not know enough about Ubuntu to actually answer questions and things to get rep. If they need to comment on a question that is not theres it should be much easier to. I think that it would be very beneficial for newbies to be able to post if someone approves.